# Power of Ultra Instinct

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In the dragon ball universe, there are plenty of methods to significantly boost the power level of the user. We have things such as Potara earrings, Saiyan power-ups, etc. But more recently we were introduced to Ultra Instinct. As this is said to be a form attainable by anyone but mostly used by gods (which is even difficult for them to attain) how strong is it actually? Like how much does it power up an individual that uses it?

This question is mainly based on episode 115 where Goku used Ultra Instinct against Kefla as well as against Jiren in an earlier episode. In SSB form Goku was eventually outmatched even with Kaioken activated. We know for a fact that SS forms basically boost power and speed significantly at the cost of stamina and ki over time. Ultra Instinct is a state of the body, making it respond without having to process the thoughts; making the body capable of an instant perfect reflex to anything.

Goku was able to dodge all of Kefla's attacks which seemed like slow motion to him most likely. But he wasn't powered up. Ultra Instinct doesn't provide ki and such it simply is a state of the body making your reflexes perfect with no time delay. So where does the power output come from? How come his punches and such are stronger with Ultra Instinct compared to all his other forms?

As far as I understand each time he was in his none powered up form, his base form. This means his power level is a lot lower than even kaioken in base form. How come he is capable of having such a damage output? Does this mean a design flaw in Ultra Instinct?

What is the **actual** power of Ultra Instinct apart from making muscle reflexes perfect?

Comment: There is another theory going around for few months that there are two types of Ultra Instincts, defensive and attacking. While Goku is said to have only the defensive half. Also Goku still hasn't fully mastered ultra instinct completely so it is hard to predict full power of ultra instinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very important factor which was mentioned multiple times in the episode was that Goku was fatigued. This was mentioned a lot of times by Champa and including Beerus. This is very likely the writers trying to say that if Goku was at full power, he would've been able to face Kefla. So I think one can't jump to a definite conclusion whether Kefla is stronger than SSJB+Kaioken Goku. The last kick landed on him by Kefla was obviously not as strong as her previous attacks so, in other words, you could assume that Goku was extremely fatigued which resulted in him losing his form

All Super Saiyan forms are multipliers to the base form. We know for a fact that the SSJG multiplier is superior to the SSJ3 multiplier and obviously, the SSJB multiplier is a lot higher than the SSJG multiplier(Based on Goku's fights with Jiren and Kefla). The multiplier would remain the same whether Goku is fatigued or not but what would change is his initial base power. The UI transformation is also a power multiplier which also makes him reach a state with complete mastery of self-movement. This is because we see Android 17 remark on how goku managed to overcome the drastic power difference and go toe to toe with Jiren. Also, we see Picollo state how he was growing stronger with every blow. Finally, when Dyspo and Toppo attacked, we know for a fact that full power Toppo is superior to SSJB but UI Goku was easily able to push him back and not just dodge his attack. So it is obvious that even the UI transformation acts like a power multiplier.

Lets say Kefla manages to achieve Super Saiyan 3 during the course of battle with UI Goku or if we see Jiren fighting seriously at full power against UI Goku, we can gauge it's power. As of now, we don't exactly know how strong the transformation is.

Comment: UI being a power multiplier makes sense, since it significantly boost the user it's speed due to perfect reflexes. Kinda off-topic right now but that implies that speed is more important than ki/stamina in the Dragon Ball universe or am I thinking wrong now? Since he was fatigued he couldm't overcome Kefla with stamina and ki alone, but with speed (UI powerup) he turned the tables... from what was shown.

Comment: Actually no, UI doesn't actually increase speed, it helps improve reaction time. Goku still has the same speed but he reacts to it an attack a lot faster. This was mentioned by Whis during their training that every part of their body should learn to react on it's own. It's obvious in the dragon ball universe most humans move at superhuman speed(Probably even faster than light). So normally if Kefla were to throw a punch, goku's brain would transmit a signal to his hand which would result in him blocking the bunch. The UI transformations eliminates this process which makes him react faster.

Comment: As far as I understood it goku was surprised when she appeared behind him and took a surprise hit. Or did I misunderstand the look on his face (at least in the anime) ?   The stamina thing I understood was only that he won't be able to do kaioken for a prolonged time due to him being out of stamina.

Comment: It was mentioned both by Whis multiple times during the tournament of power and even by the old Kai during the Universe 6 vs 7 matches that the SSJB transformations require a lot of stamina. On top of that, stacking kaioken requires even more stamina. If goku had the energy, he could've used SSJB + Kaioken times 20 and destroyed Kefla or even Kaioken times 10 but he couldn't. One good example would be to take the cell saga where gohan's power gets cut in half after saving Vegeta. He was still in his SSJ2 transformation, hence the multiplier stayed intact however, his base power was cut

Answer (score 0):

First of all **Ultra Instinct** is not a power. It's a state of mind as explained by Whis, which allows to move with purpose, batting away powerful attacks with ease and dodging them effortlessly. This was the introduction of the technique known as Migatte no Goku'i, a.k.a. Mastery of Self-Movement, or Ultra Instinct.

For more information, refer to [Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Ultra_Instinct).

Answer (score 0):

Ultra Instinct does provide power, but in a different way than just *ki* increase (which is what Whis alludes to in conversation with the Oracle Fish on Beerus's planet). UI increases your power by removing oneself from the body's self-limitation, allowing one to fight at peak condition beyond the point of their previous limitations… it's like Saitama (from *One Punch Man*) removing his limiter… meaning, the power that Goku has in SSJ Blue? He now fights beyond that limitation, beyond his body's limitation, which allows him to pull from a deeper well of power than what he was even aware of himself.

Comment: I disagree that Ultra Instinct has anything to do with pulling power out of some mystical place in one's body. Thats what the super saiyan transformations are doing and Ultra Instinct is not a SS transformation. Ultra Instinct uses your mastery of fighting to allow your body to fight without the delay caused by conscious action. It appears as a speed increase because the body responds immediately to attacks without any delay. The power gain was because Goku was using his strength more efficiently, like how you can get more pressure with the same energy in a narrow tube than in a wide tank.

Answer (score -3):

I dont agree Ultra Instinct doesnt provide power. Piccolo states that as Goku continues fighting Jiren in Ultra Instinct he keeps evolving, being his punches faster, sharper and **stronger.**

> This state is achieved by breaking the walls of one's limits and
>   getting to the deeper potential within. This state while initially
>   increasing the user's capacities vastly more than even X20 Super
>   Saiyan Blue Kaio-ken, the equally augmented mental parameters allow
>   the user to quickly and noticeable imprint on the battle, **steadily
>   evolving their power** and efficiency with each exchange

http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Ultra_Instinct_%22Omen%22

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are contradicting yourself here... strength is a form of power, speed produces more power. Sharper is similar to accuracy which allows you to deliver the full power impact. Making the body itself faster is a power boost. Momentum wise, the higher the speed; the bigger the power.

Comment: I see no contradiction. With more power I mean also more strenght. What I wanted to point out is you believe Ultra Instinct doesnt provide ki or power, I dont think that's the case at all. The increase in power of Goku (strenght, energy, etc.) as pointed out by Piccolo, 17, Zeno,etc.  is the result of an increase in ki. In Dragon Ball an increase in ki is an increase in power

Comment: BTW, aparently hundreds of fans understood from that episode that Ultra Instict doesnt provide power or ki and it's just about speed and reflexes, but it was also commented by Dragon Ball youtubers that this assumption is wrong. Though I guess you can argue the Youtubers are wrong and not the fans, personally I got the idea that Ultra Instinct increases not only speed and reflexes but ki (and therefore power and therefore strenght) from the Goku vs Jiren episode dialogues

Comment: The youtubers simply provide their opinion on what they've seen making it not factual since it's an opinion. In the actual episode it was however said that there was no ki detected from the UI form. Whis explained it as well during the training session where Goku and Vegeta were still aiming for SSB. The example was that his bare feet can avoid poop, but with a shoe on it he can't, because the feet doesn't react to it. I'd honestly believe Whis over ANY youtuber.