# Power of M.U.I transformation

Tags: dragon-ball-super

So in DBS (now that the last episode has aired). Where exactly does mastered Ultra Instinct rank?

We know that Jiren is a mortal with god level strength. And we know that Mastered Ultra Instinct matched and overpowered Jiren until it's end state.

But where does it classify? Greater than god or something? I know trying to understand power rankings in Dragon Ball is quite a pain but I am curious as to if any interviews, trivia, video game etc. Have shed any light on this.

Previously, it was established that the power of ultra instinct is in unconscious attack and defense but it's clearly shown that it's power goes beyond kaiokenx10 ssb. So now that everything is set in stone.

Where does it rank?

This is related: [Power of Ultra Instinct](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43308/power-of-ultra-instinct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, In case of Goku, just like you said, the **Mastered Ultra Instinct Transformation** is not just a skill but also a power multiplier which is immensely greater than SSJB + Kaioken*20. We know this based on Jiren's fights with Goku using this form and Mastered Ultra Instinct.
In terms of where it stands, we cannot arrive at a definite answer but we can scale his power relative to other characters the following ways.

- It has been established without a doubt both in the Anime and the Manga that Jiren is **God of destruction tier**. At the same time, All Gods of destructions are at different levels of strength. We know this based on Vados's comment in *Episode 28* where she stated that Beerus was stronger than Champa. We also know this based on *Manga Chapter 28* where Beerus manages to overwhelm multiple Gods of destruction.
- It has been hinted in the anime by Whis in *Episode 110* and stated definitely by Toppo in *Manga Chapter 29* that Jiren is stronger than Vermouth, The Universe 11 God of destruction.
- In *Episode 92* Whis implied that Vermouth might be stronger than Beerus and there exists a mortal even stronger than Vermouth,  to which Beerus replied that he only beat him in an arm  wrestling match. However, in the Manga, it was indicated that Quitella, The God of destruction of Universe 4 was the fighter who beat Beerus in an arm wrestling match.
- At the end of the fight in *Manga Chapter 24*, we see Quitella , Beerus and Vermouth were more or less the Gods with the least amount of damage on them and still able to stand. So I think it is fair to assume that these Gods are the strongest and Jiren's power is indeed relative to High tier Gods of destruction.
- When Goku was transforming to **Mastered UI**, one of the magazine spoilers the week before indicated that Jiren was going to concentrate all his power into a single punch and attack Goku. This attack was flicked away like nothing by Goku in *Episode 129*. We also see Goku initially completely overwhelm Jiren in *Episode 130*, until Jiren uses his limit breaking power where he slightly had the upper hand until Goku powered up furthur.
- Based on this, it can be established that **Jiren's limit breaking power** puts him **above** God of destruction tier and the fact that Goku with that level of stamina  remaining, managed to beat Jiren, makes him **greater** than God of Destruction tier.
- The High Tier Gods of destruction like Beerus cannot be underestimated. So based on my argument, I think it is fair to assume. Hidden Power Unlocked Jiren at full power at the **very least is relative and if not stronger** than High Tier Gods of destruction and the fact that Goku managed to beat him also with a **skill Gods struggle to attain**, makes him superior to God of destruction tier.
- The characters above Gods of Destruction shown on the show so far would be the Angels and the Grand Priest(Maybe even the Omni King's body guards considering how terrified Beerus was in *Episode 41* or maybe he was afraid of Omni King in general also note: Omni Kings cannot fight). I think it is fair to assume Goku hasn't reached that level of strength. This is because we know Whis is able to knock out Beerus with just a tap on his forehead without any effort and at the same time, the angels have all mastered Ultra Instinct for a long amount of time before Goku. So it is fair to assume Goku is no where close to an angels level of strength considering he didn't destroy Jiren with that much ease

So, based on my argument I would rank Mastered Ultra Instinct Goku this way.

1. Grand Priest
2. High Tier Angels
3. Low Tier Angels
4. Mastered Ultra Instinct Goku
5. Jiren and High Tier Gods of destruction(Jiren could be stronger but not substantially)